# Email Delivery 404

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

my team had follow the document (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/messageDefinitionSends.htm) and (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/messageDefinitionSends.htm). However, we meet some issue that the API shows success but not receive the email that we choose. Please check out the link including the coding we had, we used the second API to check the status, and it shows 404.

Coding Screen shoot: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_lOr2aOADtqFWNB4EhvnIdk4fgZiRJFx?usp=sharing
Delivery links: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/messageDefinitionSends.htm

Is there anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: according to the docs, this means `Your request cannot find any available data. Ensure you properly created your request.` (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm) Which likely means that there was an issue with either your Triggered Send Definition or the subscriber you are passing.

Comment: I have had issues with List Detective preventing imports and sends to domains that do not end in '.com', '.net', etc.  I would verify the email address you are using is considered valid by SFMC. That may be what is causing the issue. If so, speaking with SFMC, they should be able to adjust it if you have a valid use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will commonly receive a 404 error if that the accessToken that you are using in your Authorization header is not related to the MID (Business Unit) where the Triggered Send Definition resides.

You will need to ensure that the Installed Package (that you create to obtain your OAuth credentials) uses the same MID as where your Triggered Send resides.

Answer (score 0):

You must verify, that your Triggered Send Definitions are running, and not only published. Also, remember to pause, publish and start the TSDs each time you update the email content, as it will otherwise not be reflected in the emails that are sent out.